# Multiple radio buttons with same set of options

Tags: javascript, angular

I have four sets of radio buttons, each containing four options as shown in the code below:

```
    <div *ngFor="let index of [0,1,2,3]">
        <label *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" class="radio">
            <input type="radio" 
                   id="radio1" 
                   [value]="vehicle" 
                   (change)="updateValues(vehicles, formArray.value, index)"
                   name="vehicle" formControlName="vehicle">
            {{vehicle.name}} ({{vehicle.total_no}})
        </label>
    </div>
```

Each vehicle in the above option set has a name and total number attached to it. On selecting a vehicle, the total number value should update. The option should also be disabled if the total number is zero.

I have written a function that correctly updates the values, but it unfortunately registers changes in the other sets of radio buttons too.

```
  updateValues(vehicles, form, index) {
    let x;
    let selectedVehicles = form.map(x => x.vehicle);
    if (this._prevSelectedVehicles[index] === '') {
      x = vehicles.indexOf(selectedVehicles[index]);
      vehicles[x].total_no -= 1;
      this._prevSelectedVehicles[index] = selectedVehicles[index];
      this.updateTime(form, selectedVehicles);
    } else if (
      selectedVehicles[index].name !== this._prevSelectedVehicles[index].name
    ) {
      x = vehicles.indexOf(this._prevSelectedVehicles[index]);
      vehicles[x].total_no += 1;
      x = vehicles.indexOf(selectedVehicles[index]);
      vehicles[x].total_no -= 1;
      this._prevSelectedVehicles[index] = selectedVehicles[index];
      this.updateTime(form, selectedVehicles);
    }
  }
```

How can I make sure that the values selected in the previous divs are not updated? Also attaching a mockup if the question is unclear.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an unique ID for each vehicle-object and compare by this. E.g.

```
...

if(vehicles[x].id === this._prevSelectedVehicles[index].id){

     x = vehicles.indexOf(this._prevSelectedVehicles[index]);
     vehicles[x].total_no += 1;
     x = vehicles.indexOf(selectedVehicles[index]);
     vehicles[x].total_no -= 1;
     this._prevSelectedVehicles[index] = selectedVehicles[index];

} 

...
```